# In pandas, when removing data using str.split, how can I skip rows?

Tags: pandas, numpy

I have the following data:

```
Name    X   Y
AA:AA   0   0
AA:BB   1   1
AA:CC   2   2
GG:AB   3   3
GG:AC   4   4
```

How can I filter out 'AA' and the semicolon, but skip anything with GG?
I have used this to filter out the colon, and only keep the right side of the data, but for GG, I need to keep it as is

```
data['Name'] = data['Name'].str.split(":").str[1]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) and work on slice as:

```
mask = df['Name'].str.contains('GG')
df.loc[~mask,'Name'] = df.loc[~mask,'Name'].str.split(':').str[1]

print(df)
    Name  X  Y
0     AA  0  0
1     BB  1  1
2     CC  2  2
3  GG:AB  3  3
4  GG:AC  4  4
```